# Multiple envs, dotenv Flutter app, gradle issue

Tags: flutter, gradle, environment-variables

I am working on envs for my app. I use `flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2` so I have created three files `.env.development, .env.production, .env.staging` and configured android studio settings like so:
[image]

and my `main()`:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  const environment =
      String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR', defaultValue: 'development');
  print("ENV: $environment");
  await dotenv.load(fileName: '.env.${environment}');
  {......}
}
```

For the first run everything work well but if I switch env in andorid studio and run app there is a gradle error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I fix it by running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`. After that, the application works. My question is how to skip this problem? It is annoying every time type run clean and pub get.

Edit: assets files in main directory:
[image]

assets files in package directory:
[image]

Comment: This error occurs also if I try run app in Terminal by command `flutter run --dart-define=FLAVOR="production"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Delete `pubspec.lock` file
2. Do `flutter pub get`
3. Run the project

And it worked.

Comment: No, it is not works for me. I must run `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` for the first time it is works but if I change env error appears so I need to again type these commands.

Comment: have you tried `Invalidate Caches and restart`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, still the same error.

Comment: do you have assets in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is something strange with this assets, because if I comment the selected enviornament starts every time without errors.

Comment: check if you have any `assets` is not founded by `pubspec.yaml` maybe for typo you will get Waring for that after `packages get`

Comment: Finally, I know where is the problem. I have packages and one of them I have pubspec.yaml file with assets correspoding to file in the main directory, like so:```flutter:
  assets:
    - ../../.env.development
    - ../../.env.staging
    - ../../.env.production```, If I comment the error doesn't appear, but I need this.

Comment: can you paste image of this asset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247054/discussion-between-mackow-and-samina).